# How to DRY up Template Helpers in meteor?

Tags: meteor

**My Template helper has duplicated code:**

```
Template.foodMenu.helpers({
  breakfast: function() {
    var breakfastItems = EatingTimes.find(// query for breakfast items);
    // function to sort breakfastItems in here (code duplication)
  },
  lunch: function() {
    var lunchItems = EatingTimes.find(// query for lunch items);
    // function to sort lunchItems in here (code duplication)
  },
  dinner: function() {
    var dinnerItems = EatingTimes.find(// query for dinner items);
    // function to sort breakfastItems in here (code duplication)
  }
);
```

**I would like to DRY it up:**

```
Template.foodMenu.helpers({
  breakfast: function() {
    var breakfastItems = EatingTimes.find(// query for breakfast items);
    sortFoodItems(breakfastItems);
  },
  lunch: function() {
    var lunchItems = EatingTimes.find(// query for lunch items);
    sortFoodItems(lunchItems);
  },
  dinner: function() {
    var dinnerItems = EatingTimes.find(// query for dinner items);
    sortFoodItems(dinnerItems);
  }
);
```

**Where do I place this function so I can DRY up? How do I name space it so I can call it properly? I am using Iron Router if that makes a difference.**

```
var sortFoodItems = function (foodItems) { 
  // code to sort out and return foodItems to particular method that calls it   
};
```

Comment: Just place it in the same file (at the top level) as your helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define you function before helpers in the same file

```
var sortFoodItems = function (foodItems) { 
  // code to sort out and return foodItems to particular method that calls it   
};

Template.foodMenu.helpers({
  breakfast: function() {
    var breakfastItems = EatingTimes.find(/* query for breakfast items */);
    sortFoodItems(breakfastItems);
  },
  lunch: function() {
    var lunchItems = EatingTimes.find(/* query for lunch items */);
    sortFoodItems(lunchItems);
  },
  dinner: function() {
    var dinnerItems = EatingTimes.find(/* query for dinner items */);
    sortFoodItems(dinnerItems);
  }
});
```

If you want to use sortFoodItems function in multiple files, create folder with name lib and put the function in file functions.js without var keyword to make it global. For example:

```
//lib/functions.js
sortFoodItems = function (foodItems) { 
  // code to sort out and return foodItems to particular method that calls it   
};
```

You need to understand how Meteor reads your project directories. Read more about [structuring your application](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) in Meteor docs.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a global helper for this using `Template.registerHelper(name, function)` which would look like:

```
Template.registerHelper('menuItems', function(eatingTime, sortCriteria) {
  //do some checking of your arguments
  eatingTime = eatingTime || '/* your default eating time */';
  sortCriteria = sortCriteria || {/* your default sort criteria */};
  check(eatingTime, String);
  check(sortCriteria, Object);

  //find and sort your items in one mongo query or you could do separate find and sort if you want
  menuItems = EatingTimes.find({time: eatingTime}, sortCriteria);

  return menuItems; 
});
```

This would be the most *meteoric* way of DRYing up your code.

and then in your template, you could call it as:

```
{{#each menuItems 'time args' 'sort arg'}}
```